# Recover from or repair a corrupt password protected Word 2010 file

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I created a password-protected Word 2010 document at work, brought it home using a flash drive, tried opening it using Word 2007, and it won't open. It doesn't even present me with a password-entry box. Word runs, but flat out refuses to open the doc. I have the password, but what bloody good is it when I'm not presented with the password input dialogue?

OpenOffice Writer yields no joy, and WordPad tells me the document is either 'Corrupt or protected under Rights Management.' NotePad opens it quite willingly, and I see frequent references to 'encryption' that look coherent, with large blocks of text that did look so.

WinZip says the file is 'not a valid archive', which an unencrypted Word 2010 file should be a valid archive.

Is there anything I can do to recover this file?

Answer (score 2):

You would first need to verify if the document in question is open protected (the password is only needed to open the document) or if the document is encrypted (which means the password is used to decrypt the document).

If it is the first then you may still be able to get the content extracted by recovering the text in Microsoft Word. If it is the latter then I'm afraid there is probably no way to recover the data. If the data is corrupted then decryption process won't work and there is no easy way to get the data back.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft's built in repair option.  Instructions on how to do that and other recovery options can be found [here](http://www.thatdanny.com/2008/07/07/how-do-i-repair-a-corrupted-word-file-corrupted-microsoft-word-files-that-wont-open/)

You may also be missing a patch.  Download and install the patch described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969961) (even though it may be difficult with your friend lacking internet access.

Additionally, next time, consider using an online utility or document managing solution such as **Google Docs** now known as [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider using Microsoft inbuilt repair Option.

To open a specific document by using the Open and Repair feature in Word, follow these steps:

Start Word.

On the File menu, click Open.

Note In Word 2007 or Word 2010, click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Open.

In the Open dialog box, click to select the file that you want to open.

Click the down arrow on the Open button, and then click Open and Repair.

Comment: Can you stop linking to that article which results in the reader being told paid software is the ultimate solution?

Comment: Mr. Ramhound, I am just trying to share a solution i explore to serve. If it goes to a paid tool, it's up to the user to buy it or not. This is so sad that besides of being getting appreciation for what i shared, i am receiving unexpected response.
I never thought of such experience, at least not here at superuser

Comment: I appreciate quality answers, not answers that link to a blog post, which just tells users to use paid software.  You have provided a link to the same blog in several of your answers, this indicates to me, your trying to promote that website.

Comment: Enough, Now this is something i really never expected to get such a response from Superuser.

I have multiple websites bookmarked in my browser, And i am sorry to be a part of this website. Disappointed

Comment: I am disappointed for other reasons.  The quality of your answers can be better, and you don't have to link to articles, in order to do so.

Comment: Well the way you have said me now, could be said previously as well. I respect everyone's effort in making this site what it is today. And if i go wrong somewhere, there is always a better way to mention that.

Comment: The way I said it originally was from the persepctive I have seen 3 answers all linking to the same website from one author, all answers to 2 year old questions, and the quality of the other answers I read ranging from anywhere from barely acceptable to low quality.

Comment: You are indeed linking to spammy websites, which is not appreciated.

Comment: I've stopped answering to such questions .... even if i have any solution... You people may please take any necessary action on such queries...