# How to repair a corrupted word 2013 document?

Tags: documents, microsoft-word-2013

Yesterday I was working on a very important Microsoft Word (2013) document, when it suddenly crashed. Upon trying to reopen the file Word said: “The file is corrupted and cannot be opened”. I have tried all of the other methods of restoring it, such as opening it in a different program, or opening it and choosing "open and repair" in MS Word.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/444121/how-to-recover-data-from-or-repair-a-corrupt-word-2010-file

Comment: "All other methods" were just those two things listed, or did you try anything else? Of the things you did try, what were the results when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

First, make a copy of the file. Change the extension from .doc/.docx to RTF or TXT. Another possibility is converting or printing it to PDF.

Word also has a plain-text recovery tool you may not have tried. First, put a copy of the file in a folder by itself. Open Word and go to File -> Open and navigate to the folder containing the copy of the file by itself.

From the File type drop down, select "Recover Text From Any File" (see screenshot) then try opening it again.

If none of that works, you could try a third-party program called Office Recovery. http://www.officerecovery.com/

[image]